# Android Sample Apps

Tags: android

Can I use the sample apps and edit them to publish them on the market?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you talking about copyright?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it's the Apache 2.0 license. See [he famous NotePad demo](http://code.google.com/p/android-positron/source/browse/trunk/notepad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotesList.java?spec=svn118&r=118)

Comment: +1 For those who don't know, the Notepad demo is "famous" as it has been uploaded on to the Market countless times.

Answer (score 1):

The content is [Creative Commons Attribution 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/).

Comment: Uh? Google code is released under Apache license.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/license.html  Some of the content of the android site itself is licensed under creative commons, however the majority of things dev related are licensed under Apache.